# Adding support for settings screen android

Tags: java, android

I'am using several CheckBoxPreference in my android app to add a settings menu. But is there a way to say that one and only one CheckBoxPreference **MUST** be checked at the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, but it could certainly be improved!

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity{

    CheckBoxPreference cb1;
    CheckBoxPreference cb2;
    CheckBoxPreference cb3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        cb1 = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("CheckBox1");
        cb2 = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("CheckBox2");
        cb3 = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("CheckBox3");
        cb1.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Listener());
        cb2.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Listener());
        cb3.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Listener());

    }

    private class Listener implements OnPreferenceChangeListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if((Boolean) newValue) 
                removeOthers(preference.getKey());
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void removeOthers(String key) {
        if(key.equals("CheckBox1")) {
            cb2.setChecked(false);
            cb3.setChecked(false);
        }
        else if(key.equals("CheckBox2")) {
            cb1.setChecked(false);
            cb3.setChecked(false);
        }
        else if(key.equals("CheckBox3")) {
            cb1.setChecked(false);
            cb2.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic logic:

```
int numOfCheck = 0;

//Check each checkbox
if(checkbox1.checked){
    numOfCheck+=1;
}

//... Add other checkboxes

if(numOfCheck>1||numOfCheck<1){
    //... Alert the user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html).